# First generation iPod for development

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, appcelerator

I just found an iPod first generation. Can this version (1.1.5) be used for development?
Can you make an iOS 4 software version restore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3.1.3 actually a good platform to test on if you want to support all Apple's devices. But I would recommend getting a new iPod/iPhone to test iOS 4.

Answer (score 4):

iOS 4 cannot run on a first- (or second-) generation iPod or iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily install iPhone OS 3.1.3 onto it and use it for development. That's the maximum available version for this device.

You'll also need to set `Deployment Target` in your project settings in Xcode to 3.1.3 or lower.